# fisher's exact test with values less than 1

Tags: r, fishers-exact-test

I have a rxc contingency table that has values that are less than 1.

For Example:

```
        satisfication
income  VeryD LittleD
< 15k  2e-03  0.0057
15-25k 8e-04  0.0013
25-40k 1e-03  0.0010
> 40k  4e-03  0.0237
```

I receive the following error:

Error in fisher.test(Job) : FEXACT error 3.
All elements of TABLE are zero.
PRT and PRE are set to missing values.
In addition: Warning message:
In fisher.test(Job) :
  'x' has been rounded to integer: Mean relative difference: 1

Is there something I can do to get around this error? I am not using counts but data that is normalized to account for volume.

Comment: What are veryD and LittleD?

Comment: Use the counts.

Comment: You can't "normalize to account for volume" and get a correct test. If you need to have some exposure measure included in the model, could (perhaps) look at a Poisson GLM with an offset.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the site.  If you don't have counts, you don't have a contingency table and you shouldn't use Fisher's exact test.

It looks like you are modeling satisfaction related to income and that satisfaction is on some sort of ordinal scale. I suggest that a good starting place, at least, would be ordinal logistic regression.